# Highlighting cell if one date is after another?

Tags: excel, date, conditional-formatting

I have a couple columns of data, and I am trying to highlight those instances where the second date occurs before the first, to show if there are any mistakes in the data.

```
ID  Start Date  End Date
1    01/01/15    01/15/15
2    01/06/15    01/02/15
3    01/06/15    01/03/15
4    01/11/15    01/13/15
```

I would like to be able to highlight the cells where the end date is earlier than the start date. All of the date conditional formatting links I have been directed to are for basing it off of current date, or one specific date, and I am kind of lost.

Thanks!

Comment: Show what you have tried / read already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kinda complicated if you have no coding experience. The best way to solve this problem is to write a VBA script yourself. So I will go Step by step with the process of doing that with the complete code.

1) Open your Excel file, then go to the Developer Tab.

(If you do not see it, go to File->Options, Click on Customize Ribbon, and add click on Developer for the main tabs.

2) Click on the Visual Basic button, under the developer tab.

3a) Paste the following code in:

`Sub ColorCellsWithIncorrectEndDate()
    Dim Rows
    Rows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For i = 2 To Rows
        If Cells(i, 2).Value > Cells(i, 3).Value Then
            Cells(i, 3).Select
            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 65535
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub`

3b) The code above works if your excel sheet is in the exact same format it was listed above.

--If the cells are not in the same columns, then you will adjust the numbers that are in "Cells(i,#)" so that the number corresponds to the column. (ie. A=1, B=2, C=3...). Right now it is checking for column B (Start Date) to be greater than column C (End Date). And is then coloring Cell C if it is true.

--If the cells are not in the right row then you adjust the line that says "For i = # To Rows" The Number corresponds directly to the row number.

--If you want a different color then go to this website: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp, and replace the "65535" with any one of those valid numbers.

4) SAVE and exit out of visual basic

5) Return to your Excel Sheet and click Developer->Macros. (A dialog box will appear)

6) Select "ColorCellsWithIncorrectEndDate" in the dialog box, and click Run.

7) All the end dates that are past the start date will be highlighted in yellow (or whatever color you chose)

Hope this helps!

-BlindingFog

Answer (score 0):

Dates can be compared by < just like numbers. One possibility would be to research how to do conditional formatting which highlights the smallest entry in each row. If any row has the second rather than the first date column highlighted then it is a problem row.

It is also possible to do it more directly. The key thing to do when none of the predefined conditional rules work is to use `Conditional Formatting/New Rule/Use a formula to determine which cells to format`. If the data that you show starts in A1 (so that 01/15/15 is in C2), go to C2 and create a conditional formatting rule given by the formula

```
= C2 < B2
```

Then -- just paste the formatting down the rest of the dates in column C